# framework for distributed algorithm

Tags: frameworks, distributed, pagerank

I have to do a project where I have a dynamic graph and each node execute my algorithm to calculate the pagerank.
My question is: There is a framwork that allows me to run an algorithm in the same time in each node (the algorithm is not centralized)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Giraph is probably the most common example for it and can do exactly what you are looking for. However it isn't trivial to set up, there is a question from yesterday on SO about materials for Giraph: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817423/material-related-to-giraph/

Another example would be GraphX (http://amplab.github.io/graphx/) from spark and GraphLab (http://graphlab.org/projects/index.html), but I don't have any experience with those. However all of those frameworks enable writing code for a node and execute it for each node in a graph. They also allow you to distribute the algorithm across multiple servers for large graphs, but it isn't necessary if your graph is small enough.

Comment: Are there tutorials for using these tools with Python?  Giraph is Java based and GraphX appears to be written in Scala and Java.  Spark is supposed to now be Python compatible (pyspark) so presumably GraphX and Giraph are too.  Any tips/links?

Comment: @Gleen, For Giraph I don't know and couldn't imagine any way to implement code in another language, but Java. I didn't use the others though.